# Pick up connection if there is a disconnect

Tags: sql-server, node.js, tedious

I make use of this specific version: https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql/tree/v3.3.0#multiple-connections of the SQL Server npm package.

I have been looking through the documentation of tedious (the underlying lib) and Microsofts documentation (see the github link above).

I couldn't find anything that does something simple like `getCurrentConnection`, or `getConnectionStatus` or anything similar.

I had two ways to solve this problem but I'm not happy with both of them so that's why I'm asking here.

My first approach was to set a timeout and let the connect function call itself on each `catch(err)`.

The second one was to handle this in the middleware but then if all is working fine it will make a connection to SQL on every request and closing that connection again.

My middleware function:

```
api.use(function(err, req, res, next){
   sql.close();
   sql.connect(config.database).then(() => {
     next();
   }).catch(function(err) {
     sql.close();
     server.main();
   });
});
```

I want to, if possible pick up the connection instead of closing and starting a new one with regards to when the server or the database crashes I still have some data from the existing function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the help of Arnold I got to understand the mssql package and it's inner workings a lot better.

Therefor I came up with the following solution to my problem.

```
let intervalFunction;
const INTERVAL_DURATION = 4000;

if (require.main === module){
    console.log("Listening on http://localhost:" + config.port + " ...");
    app.listen(config.port);
    // try to connect to db and fire main on succes. 
    intervalFunction = setInterval(()=> getConnection(), INTERVAL_DURATION);
}

function getConnection() {
  sql.close();
  sql.connect(config.database).then(() => {
    sql.close();
    clearInterval(intervalFunction);
    main();
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
    console.log(`DB connection will be tried again in ${INTERVAL_DURATION}ms`)
    sql.close();
  });
}
```

Once the initial connection has been made but it got lost in the meantime the pool will pick up the connection automatically and handle your connections

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you basically want to reuse connections. Tedious has built-in connection pooling, so you don't have to worry about re-using them:

```
var config = {
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: '...',
    pool: {
        max: 10,
        min: 0,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
    }
}
```

In the example above (just copied from the GitHub URL you've posted), there will be 10 connections in the pool ready to use. Here's the beauty: the pool manager will handle all connection use and re-use for you, i.e., the number of connections are elastic based on your app's needs.

As you've mentioned, what about DB crashes? That too is built-in: connection health-check:

> Internally, each Connection instance is a separate pool of TDS
>   connections. Once you create a new Request/Transaction/Prepared
>   Statement, a new TDS connection is acquired from the pool and reserved
>   for desired action. Once the action is complete, connection is
>   released back to the pool. Connection health check is built-in so once
>   the dead connection is discovered, it is immediately replaced with a
>   new one.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Arnold, thanks for your quick reply, the things you describe all go about the fact that you are connected. But in my question I specify that sometimes our api starts up before the db. How would you go about that? The way I specified but not in a middleware function? So keep retrying on catch(err) or is there a cleaner way without timeout?

Comment: if I use this code:
`code`
function getConnection() {
  sql.close();
  sql.connect(config.database).then(() => {
  sql.close();
      main();
      console.log('werkt wel');
  }).catch(function(err) {
    sql.close();
    console.log('werk niet')
    setTimeout(()=> {
      getConnection(), 2000
    })
  });
}
`code`

And I turn on sql server with docker start the timeout function will stop. It will work once I restart the node process but that I don't want to do.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but IMO you have two options here to resolve this racing condition (DB not ready when app starts): 1) fail to start the app. That's what I usually do. Then I deal with this problem in the startup scripts. In my cases, there's absolutely no point in starting the app at all (!) if the DB isn't ready. 2) have the app keep polling the DB and continue on until the db is ready. That's OK too, but that at one point this needs to fail if the DB never becomes ready. It looks like that's what you did below.